# How to use GridSearchCV with MultiOutputClassifier(MLPClassifier) Pipeline

Tags: python, scikit-learn, multiclass-classification

I am trying out scikit-learn for the first time, for a **Multi-Output Multi-Class text classification** problem. I am attempting to use `GridSearchCV` to optimize the parameters of `MLPClassifier` for this purpose.

I will admit that I am shooting in the dark here, having no prior experience. Please let me know if this makes sense.

Below is what I currently have:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from sklearn.multioutput import MultiOutputClassifier
from sklearn.neural_network import MLPClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score

df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')

df.fillna('', inplace=True) #Replaces NaNs with "" in the DataFrame (which would be considered a viable choice in this multi-classification model)

x_features = df['input_text']
y_labels = df[['output_text_label_1', 'output_text_label_2']]

x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x_features, y_labels, test_size=0.3, random_state=7)

pipe = Pipeline(steps=[('cv', CountVectorizer()),
                       ('mlpc', MultiOutputClassifier(MLPClassifier()))])

pipe.fit(x_train, y_train)

pipe.score(x_test, y_test)
```

`pipe.score` gives a score of ~0.837, which seems to suggest that the above code is doing something. Running `pipe.predict()` on some test strings seems to yield relatively adequate output results.

However, even after looking at plenty examples, I don't understand how to implement `GridSearchCV` for this `Pipeline`. (Additionally, I would like advice on which parameters to search).

I doubt it makes sense to post my attempts with `GridSearchCV` since they have been varied and all unsuccessful. But a brief example from a Stack Overflow answer could be:

```
grid = [
        {
        'activation' : ['identity', 'logistic', 'tanh', 'relu'],
        'solver' : ['lbfgs', 'sgd', 'adam'],
        'hidden_layer_sizes': [(100,),(200,)]
        }
       ]

grid_search = GridSearchCV(pipe, grid, scoring='accuracy', n_jobs=-1)

grid_search.fit(x_train, y_train)
```

This gives the error:

> ValueError: Invalid parameter activation for estimator
> Pipeline(steps=[('cv', CountVectorizer()),
> ('mlpc', MultiOutputClassifier(estimator=MLPClassifier()))]). Check the list of
> available parameters with `estimator.get_params().keys()`.

I'm not sure what causes this, nor exactly how to utilize `estimator.get_params().keys()` to figure out which parameters are faulty.

Perhaps my uses of `'cv', CountVectorizer()` or `'mlpc', MultiOutputClassifier(estimator=MLPClassifier()))` are incorrect in relation to the grid parameters.

I believe I need to use `CountVectorizer()` here because my inputs (and desired label outputs) are all strings.

I very much appreciate an example of how `GridSearchCV` should be used for a `Pipeline` presumably utilizing `CountVectorizer()` and `MLPClassifier` in the correct way, and which grid parameters may be advisable to search.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**TL;DR** Try something like this:

```py
mlpc = MLPClassifier(solver='adam',
                     learning_rate_init=0.01,
                     max_iter=300,
                     activation='relu',
                     early_stopping=True)
pipe = Pipeline(steps=[('cv', CountVectorizer(ngram_range=(1, 1))),
                       ('scale', StandardScaler()),
                       ('mlpc', MultiOutputClassifier(mlpc))])
search_space = {
    'cv__max_df': (0.9, 0.95, 0.99),
    'cv__min_df': (0.01, 0.05, 0.1),
    'mlpc__estimator__alpha': 10.0 ** -np.arange(1, 5),
    'mlpc__estimator__hidden_layer_sizes': ((64, 32), (128, 64),
                                            (64, 32, 16), (128, 64, 32)),
    'mlpc__estimator__tol': (1e-3, 5e-3, 1e-4),
}
```

Discussion:

1. **[Edit] For multi-output binary classification only**, [`MLPClassifier`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neural_network.MLPClassifier.html) supports multi-output classification, and having interrelating outputs, I wouldn't recommend using `MultiOutputClassifier` as it trains separate `MLPClassifier` instances without taking into account the relationship between outputs. Training only one `MLPClassifier` is faster, cheaper, and usually more accurate.
2. The `ValueError` is due to improper parameter grid names. See [Nested parameters](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/compose.html#nested-parameters).
3. With a modest workstation and/or large training data, set `solver='adam'`
   to use a cheaper, first-order method as opposed to a second-order `'lbfgs'`. Alternatively, try `solver='sgd'`---even cheaper to compute---but then also tune `momentum`. I anticipate that your data will be sparse and of different scales after `CountVectorizer`, and `momentum`/`solver='adam'` is a way to tackle variant gradients.
4. Insert one of the [standardization transformers](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/preprocessing.html#preprocessing-scaler) (I guess [`StandardScaler`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler.html) will work better) after `CountVectorizer` as MLPs are sensitive to feature scaling. Although, `solver='adam'` would probably handle imbalanced bag of words well. Still, I believe it won't hurt to standardize your data.
5. I think tuning `activation` is needles. Set `activation='relu'`.
6. Use `early_stopping=True`, specify a large enough `max_iter`, and tune `tol` to prevent overfitting.
7. Definitely tune `learning_rate_init` with `solver='sgd'`; for `solver='adam'`, I assume higher learning rates will be OK and `adam` won't require comprehensive learning-rate tuning.
8. Prefer deeper nets to wider ones (e.g., `hidden_layer_sizes=(128, 64, 32)` to `hidden_layer_sizes=(256, 192)`).
9. Always tune `alpha`.
10. Optimal `hidden_layer_sizes` may depend on a document-term dimension.
11. Try setting higher `batch_size`s but take into account computational expenses.
12. If you wish to optimize [`CountVectorizer`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer.html), tune `max_df` and `min_df` but not `ngram_range`; I believe at least a two-layer MLP will handle unigram relationships itself in hidden layers without need to process n-grams explicitly.
13. Optimize the hyperparameters in the code sample above first. But note that the remaining hyperparameters can also affect both computational performance and predictive power.

**Disclaimer**: Most of the remarks are based on my (insubstantial) assumptions about your data and pertain only to scikit-learn's MLPs. Refer to [docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/neural_networks_supervised.html) to learn more about neural networks and experiment with other tips. And remember, *There is No Free Lunch*.

Comment: Thanks for a great and detailed answer. I am about to pour into this, but when trying to run your TLDR code I get the error: `ValueError: Multioutput target data is not supported with label binarization`. Any idea why, given the code I presented in my question? `.shape` of `x_train`, `x_test`, `y_train`, `y_test` gives `(3036,)` `(1302,)` `(3036, 2)` `(1302, 2)` respectively. Also note that I changed `('cv', ngram_range=(1, 1)` to `('cv', CountVectorizer(ngram_range=(1, 1))`. Thank you!

Comment: @PAN Oh, my bad. I missed that your output is *multi-class*, not binary. scikit-learn's MLP support multi-output *two-class* task setting, not multi-class. Now I see why you used `MultiOutputClassifier`. Please, check the answer edit and report your findings.

Comment: Thanks again for your answer, I have accepted it. Two follow-up questions if you don't mind: (1) Would your suggested initial search space still be a good starting place if I increase the number of features from 2 to 6? (2) Do you have any advice on scoring method?

Comment: @PAN (1) I think yes, at least for `alpha`, `tol`, and hyperparameters of `cv`. (2) The scoring method is actually not something you "tune"; you define it depending on your task, e.g., if you have an imbalanced dataset and want to discourage your model to mislabel positive samples, prefer *recall* over *accuracy*.